# "Authentication Required" wifi password request loop on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04

I have a dual-boot laptop (Surface Book 1) that can run both Windows and Ubuntu. Two days ago, on Saturday, everything was working fine. Now, only Windows can connect. On Ubuntu, it can see the wifi, and will attempt to connect, but it bounces me back to the "Authentication Required" page where I reenter the password.

I've tried restarting the router, turning my computer completely off and on, and verifying (many times) that I'm using the correct password. Among many other things! Some 5 hours of work has gone into this before I posted this question.

What can I do to resolve this?

Edit: I should mention. This appears to be a problem specifically between Ubuntu and my Xfinity wifi. When I turn my phone into a hot-spot, it connects just fine.

Comment: Please accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ next to the answer and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was!

I had updated my linux kernel on Saturday, and that had overwritten my (fairly ancient) special surface-book linux kernel that I got from Jakeday's git repository. To fix the problem, I got the newest, top-of-the-line kernel from here:
https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface

I had to make sure to follow both its installation instructions (https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup) and sign the kernel using their premade public key & associated instructions (https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Secure-Boot).

It's so nice to be done with this!